# How to import external library into android project?

Tags: android

How to add external library into android project files inside instead of importing library into work space and the adding library files.
The library jar file added into lib folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android studio, right click on your project, 'Open Module Settings', Click on the correct module, Dependencies tab, Green + button, Library dependency. Select the jar you want

Or, click and drag your jar into the libs folder...